# How to compare inner DTO fields on Nest js decorators?

Tags: nestjs

Is there a way to check the same DTO fields on decorators?

I have

```
export class MyDTO {
@ApiProperty()
id: integer;

@ApiProperty()
@MyCustomDecorator()
hasPriority: boolean;
}
```

I want to check on MyCustomDecorator() if the id is greater than 10 and the priority is true reject the entry.
Is there a way to inject the id into the hasPriority decorator?

Answer (score 0):

[conditional validation](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#conditional-validation)

[custom validation decorators](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-decorators)

`class-validator` will help you inject the object being validated.